# Understanding AWK script

Tags: scripting, awk

format of flat file :

```
;metier_code              ;
;-------------------------;

(0 rows affected)
;CRDS_Ptf_No;          ;                                ;                         ;          ;                                ; ;                         ;                         ;               ;               ;               ;                         ;                         ;     ;Status;
;-----------;----------;--------------------------------;-------------------------;----------;--------------------------------;-;-------------------------;-------------------------;---------------;---------------;---------------;-------------------------;-------------------------;-----;------;
;       NULL;ABCD      ;ABHJARS                         ;                         ;ABCD      ;ABCD                            ;Y;                         ;                         ;               ;               ;               ;                         ;                         ;     ;A     ;
;       1234;XEU-ANKD  ;XEU-AJKD                        ;                         ;ABCD      ;ABCD                            ;Y;                         ;                         ;               ;               ;               ;                         ;                         ;     ;A     ;
.
.
;      11745;ANJLDMAOKD;AMKDJ AN DJ JAHF AS CPFVH ACCR  ;NONE                     ;AN DJ JAHA;AN DJ JAHA                      ;Y;NO ANKIO GAP             ;YES AMK SCF              ;               ;               ;               ;                         ;                         ;     ;I     ;
;      11744;AMKDIONSKH;AMKDJ AN DJ JAHF AS CPFVH MTM   ;NONE                     ;AN DJ JAHA;AN DJ JAHA                      ;Y;NO ANKIO GAP             ;YES AMK SCF              ;               ;               ;               ;                         ;                         ;     ;I     ;

(5436 rows affected)
(return status = 0)

Return parameters:

;           ;
;-----------;
;       5436;


(1 row affected)
;       ;           ;
;-------;-----------;
;grepkey;       5436;

(1 row affected)
```

Below script is used to format the flat file.

```
awk -F ';' '/^;-----------;/ {start=1;next;}; start==0 {next;}; /^[^;]|^$/ { exit;}; { line_nr++; gsub(" +",""); print line_nr "" $0;}' temp_file > test
```

Below is the correct output that i am getting by using the above script .

```
1;NULL;ABCD;ABHJARS;;ABCD;ABCD;Y;;;;;;;;;A;
2;NULL;XEU-ANKD;XEU-AJKD;;ABCD;ABCD;Y;;;;;;;;;A;
3;NULL;SWAPOLEIL;SWAPOLEIL;;QWERDF;QWERDF;Y;;;;;;;;;A;
.
.
5436;11744;AMKDIONSKH;AMKDJ AN DJ JAHF AS CPFVH MTM;;QWERDF;QWERDF;Y;;;;;;;;;A;
```

CAN ANYONE PLEASE EXPLAIN ME THE BELOW AWK SCRIPT, which is used to format the file

```
awk -F ';' '/^;-----------;/ {start=1;next;}; start==0 {next;}; /^[^;]|^$/ { exit;}; { line_nr++; gsub(" +",""); print line_nr "" $0;}' temp_file > test
```

i was able to understand few things from the above script :
1) /^[^;]|^$/ { exit;}; stops the processing if a line occurs which does not start with ;
2) it is ignoring the leading lines

Answer (score 4):

Awk scripts are much easier to understand if you format them with one condition per line:

```
'/^;-----------;/ {start=1;next;};
```

On reading A line beginning with ";----------;", set the variable start to true, then go to the next line of input without printing anything.

```
start==0 {next;};
```

If start is false, go to the next line of input without printing anything.

```
/^[^;]|^$/ { exit;};
```

If a line which starts with a character other than `;` or is empty is read in, stop processing the file and exit (a simpler equivalent would be `!/^;/{exit}`)

```
{ line_nr++; gsub(" +",""); print line_nr "" $0;}
```

For all other lines, increment a counter, delete all spaces from the line, then print the counter and the updated line.

Comment: The `gsub` removes spaces, not plus signs. It's a regex.

Comment: Oops, right. It's been a while.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `awk -F ';' '/^;-----------;/ {start=1;next;}; start==0 {next;}; /^[^;]|^$/ { exit;}; { line_nr++; gsub(" +",""); print line_nr "" $0;}' temp_file > test` is a complicated version of `nl -w 1 -p -s';' temp_file > test` ([hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206391/96588) via Google).

Comment: Would be great if anyone could explain me the awk script that i shared.

Answer (score 0):

The script skips all lines (2. command) until it comes to a line starting with `;----------;` (1. command).
It then prints the following lines, removing extraneous spaces (4. command), until it reaches either an empty line or one not starting with `;` (3. command)

In short: it prints out the first block that is delimited by `;----------;` and (empty line or line not starting with `;`).